# Write dataframe to JSON with column as key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

##### Question:

Is there a way to write a dataframe as JSON and have the outermost keys be the values of a column? Using Pyspark's built-in functions is preferred and pivoting should be avoided.

##### Example input:

```
df1 = (
    spark.createDataFrame([
        ['Joe', '123 St.', '111-111-1111'],
        ['Jim', '456 Dr.', '222-222-2222'],
        ['Tim', '789 Ln.', '333-333-3333'],
    ], ['Name', 'Street', 'Phone'])
)
```

##### Desired output:

```
{
  "Joe":{"Name":"Joe","Street":"123 St.","Phone":"111-111-1111"},
  "Jim":{"Name":"Jim","Street":"456 Dr.","Phone":"222-222-2222"},
  "Tim":{"Name":"Tim","Street":"789 Ln.","Phone":"333-333-3333"}
}
```

##### Attempts:

The first attempt failed because the keys are "json" and not the values from the "Names" column:

```
df2 = (
    df1
    .groupBy('Name')
    .agg(
      collect_list(struct(df.columns)).alias('value'),
      collect_list(col('Name')).alias('key')
    )
    .select(to_json(map_from_arrays(col('key'), col('value'))).alias('json'))
)

df2.write.json('json_example2', mode='overwrite')
```

The second attempt succeeded but only when using small dataset. The problem is that pivoting in Pyspark is capped at a certain number of columns. My actual dataset is over millions of rows. When I increased the max column count, Spark did not complete the operation because it stalled.

```
df3 = (
    df1
    .select('Name', to_json(struct(*df1.columns)).alias('json'))
    .groupBy()
    .pivot('Name')
    .agg(first('json'))
)

df3.write.json('json_example3', mode='overwrite')
```

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, we transition to a NoSQL database and we are using the "Names" as indexes. But now that I think about it, we could probably specify the index as one of the nested keys rather than the outermost key... I am unsure how that works and need to look into that. If that is the case, then writing out `json_example2` would solve the problem.

Comment: Now it makes even less sense.